# How do I access shared folders by ip address? (for example, in windows, I use "\\172.16.243.7")

Tags: networking, samba

Right now, if I want to access shared folders on my network, I have to browse them via Network in nautilus. I am wandering how I can open shared folders of a PC, by its ip.

tldr; Equivalence of running "\ipaddress" in windows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way is to open Nautilus, the file manager, and press ctrl+L. This will give you a text field where you can type

```
smb://172.16.243.7/
```

You can also connect to a share using the places menu. From  the places menu, select "connect to server". In the dialog that appears, selet "Windows resource", type the IP into the "server" field. This will create a shortcut on your desktop to the share.

Answer (score 3):

> smb://172.16.243.7/

press Ctrl+L if you can't type in the location bar.

Answer (score 0):

In shortcuts menu on top left, you have access to the shared folders on your network via the "Network" folder. You should see the PC you're interested in there.

Answer (score 0):

you can also go to *places->connect to server*  then choose windows share and then type the IP address..