# Not showing up on network after running system-config-samba

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, samba, file-sharing

I am new to Ubuntu and still learning so please bear with me.  I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and trying to set up shared files between Ubuntu and Windows 7.  I did manage to get a shared file set up once, but have since lost it.  In an effort to repair the problem I installed system-config-samba, and since running the Samba GUI my Ubuntu machine no longer shows up on my network for some reason?  It use to show up in windows explorer under the network section, and when I first had the shared folder I could access it there.  Now the Ubuntu machine is no longer found?

I can not find what was changed when I ran the system-config-samba?

Update:

I had to uninstall all of Samba including system-config-samba, and then reinstall all of the software.  I ran the Samba GUI, set up new shares and my Ubuntu machine is now back in windows explorer under the network section.  AS far as I can tell, when I first installed system-config-samba it changed something in the smb.conf file causing the machine to not be displayed.

Comment: Are the Samba services `smbd` and `nmbd` started? Check with `systemctl status smbd` and `systemctl status nmbd`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Thomas.  Yes both smbd and nmbd are started. **(Please see above information in my question were I edited to include the systemctl status results.)**

Answer (score 0):

First,install samba:
 `sudo apt install samba`

The second,install the gvfs-backends:
 `sudo apt install gvfs-backends`

https://superuser.com/questions/1178972/this-file-server-type-is-not-recognized/1179710#1179710

logged out, logged in.

Open nautilus,the file manager, and press ctrl+L. This will give you a text field where you can type.
`smb://ip.ip.ip.ip/ShareName`

You can also connect to a share using the places menu. From the places menu, select "connect to server". In the dialog that appears, selet "Windows resource", type the IP into the "server" field. This will create a shortcut on your desktop to the share.

[How do I access shared folders by ip address? (for example, in windows, I use "\\172.16.243.7")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10030/how-do-i-access-shared-folders-by-ip-address-for-example-in-windows-i-use/10085#10085)